# NLP / ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, nlp, jupyter

```
import numpy as np
%matplotlib notebook 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use ('ggplot')

from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

from gensim.test.utils import datapath, get_tmpfile
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
from gensim.scripts.glove2word2vec import glove2word2vec
```

Hello everyone, I hope you all are doing well. I am new in DL and NLP. As I am learning I came across this error. Can anyone help me solve this issue? thank you all.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-8db7eebe6f3e> in <module>
      7 from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
      8 
----> 9 from gensim.test.utils import datapath, get_tmpfile
     10 from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
     11 from gensim.scripts.glove2word2vec import glove2word2vec

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gensim'
```

Comment: Have you not installed `gensim` or even after installation you are getting this error ?

Comment: I did not install it. How to install gensim?

Comment: depends on your environment. maybe `pip install gensim` or `conda install -c anaconda gensim`

Comment: Thank you all. I have installed it using pip install gensim